# Unity - Player Prefs won't save a specific UI element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I managed to get my FPS counter saved whether it was toggled on or off in the main menu when loading into the level scene, but for some reason my timer and collectible counter don't get the same justice when loading into the next scene, here is my code, much help would be appreciated, prepare for a long post as this I'm doing each ui element in separate code files.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class FPSToggleOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string startScene = "Tutorial01";
    public bool newValue;
    //UnityEngine.UI.Toggle toggle = null;
    public Toggle toggle;
    public TMP_Text fpstext;

    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("tutorial"))
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tutorial") == 1)
            {
                newValue = true;
                toggle.isOn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                newValue = false;
                toggle.isOn = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void SceneTransitioner()
    {
        //SceneManager.LoadScene(startScene);
    }

    public void Toggle_Changed(bool newValue)
    {
        if (newValue == true)
        {
            fpstext.enabled = true;
            startScene = "Tutorial01";
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tutorial", 1);
        }
        else
        {
            fpstext.enabled = false;
            startScene = "Level01";
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tutorial", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class FlowerToggleOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string startScene = "Tutorial01";
    public bool newValue;
    //UnityEngine.UI.Toggle toggle = null;
    public Toggle toggle;
    public Image flowertextimage;
    public Text flowertext;

    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("tutorial"))
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tutorial") == 1)
            {
                newValue = true;
                toggle.isOn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                newValue = false;
                toggle.isOn = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void SceneTransitioner()
    {
        //SceneManager.LoadScene(startScene);
    }

    public void Toggle_Changed(bool newValue)
    {
        if (newValue == true)
        {
            flowertext.enabled = true;
            flowertextimage.enabled = true;
            startScene = "Tutorial01";
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tutorial", 1);
        }
        else
        {
            flowertext.enabled = false;
            flowertextimage.enabled = false;
            startScene = "Level01";
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tutorial", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class TimerLoadOnToggle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string startScene = "Tutorial01";
    public bool newValue;
    //UnityEngine.UI.Toggle toggle = null;
    public Toggle toggle;
    public TMP_Text timertext;

    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("tutorial"))
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tutorial") == 1)
            {
                //fpstext.enabled = true;
                newValue = true;
                toggle.isOn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //fpstext.enabled = false;
                newValue = false;
                toggle.isOn = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void SceneTransitioner()
    {
        //SceneManager.LoadScene(startScene);
    }

    public void Toggle_Changed(bool newValue)
    {
        if (newValue == true)
        {
            timertext.enabled = true;
            startScene = "Tutorial01";
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tutorial", 1);
        }
        else
        {
            timertext.enabled = false;
            startScene = "Level01";
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tutorial", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the same thing to work with my other UI elements considering it worked with the fps counter just fine especially considering all three of these things are basically just text or TextMeshPro but it didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior. You're setting values, not saving them.

Because you seem to want a realtime effect, after using any of the `PlayerPrefs.Set*()` functions you need to call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` in order to make them persistent.

According to the documentation: *Note: Since writing the PlayerPrefs can cause hiccups, it is recommended to not call this function during gameplay.*.

So I don't recommend calling it after every `Set*()` function, but rather either after you have some sort of game workflow or before loading the next scene. Or even better, add a "Save" button for it. Setting it in `Update()` or any other function that is called often might degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are forget to save PlayerPrefs values. After `PlayerPrefs.SetInt();` you should add this line: `PlayerPrefs.Save()`